# Oracle SQL : How to filter a NUMBER column

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, varchar

The following SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column = '%'
```

will return all lines of the table TABLE.

Now, if my column is a NUMBER. How do I return all lines with a `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: `WHERE 1=1`? What do you mean?

Comment: No, can't use that. The `WHERE column = ` is always there. I need a value that will 'cancel' the filter effect. Just like the '%' for strings or '*' for regex expressions.

Comment: `where column is not null or column is null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CAST` function on `NumberColumn`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(NumberColumn AS VARCHAR(length)) = '%'
```

`CAST` and `CONVERT` take a default 30 length if not specified. ( Credits to @JaydipJ)

Comment: You need to include the length also when casting,`VARCHAR(n)`.

Comment: Yes, I've added the length, and this works. On the other hand, I don't understand why `to_char` didn't work ?

Comment: @NullException While using `Cast` or `Convert`  `VARCHAR` takes default 30 Characters length

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes, but (touching some edge case now) you do not know the field length OP has.

Comment: The field length is 5. When I don't mention the length explicitly, Oracle raises an error.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column = column or column is null
```

Will return everything and works for every data type.

Comment: but it will be same as  1 = 1. Am not clear, what OP expects actually.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Yes it would be, but I think OP has some kind of exercise. He mentioned the he cannot use where 1=1.